# Android USB Connection Not Working

Tags: android, windows, usb

I can't seem to connect my Samsung Galaxy Note II (N7100) to my Windows 8 Machine (aiming to use the phone for debugging - but current can't even connect the device as mass storage). No USB notification is shown when connecting the mobile by cable.

Things I have checked thus far:

USB Cable (works on different machine and with HTC phone)
USB Ports (tried different ports, 2.0 and 3.0, all working)
PC USB Drivers
Phone (connects to my Win 7 machine)
Samsung Kies (and Samsung driver) and Google USB Driver both installed

*PS. The reason Im asking this here is because I'm aiming to use the phone for development and I'm hoping to get some answers that aren't "have you double checked the cable?" like on every Google search I have performed so far. Hopefully another developer recognises this issue.*

Comment: I don't know if Windows 8 has the equivalent of what earlier Windows had as "Device Manager", but does your device show up there when it is plugged in?

Comment: Win 8 does have a device manager; and the device does not show up when plugged in.

Comment: I had a similar problem with my Sony device on Windows 8.1 (I've never experienced this problem before on Win7). I followed the advice from Sony Mobile forums and installed this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744 and now it works fine.

Comment: Already on Windows 8.1 Pro (Not N or KN) so I should already have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. so You've obviously done the basics and made sure all the cabling is functional.
it sounds like the Volume is not mounting in windows 8
if it's not detected in Windows Device Manager, and More importantly, if it's not visible in Disk Management, then the volume simply is not Mounting.

I would suggest

1. Try connecting to a Windows 7 Machine and see if it works, if it does, Then Most likely you need Windows 8 Drivers
2. I would be contacting Samsung Engineers for support on the Issue
3. What version of Kies are you using
4. i found this that might be useful for you

Ultimately, as you know the volume is not mounting due to Driver issues, and this needs to be resolved if you are to have a solution

1. You could always Try setting up XP Mode in Windows 8 and see if it recognizes that way.
   Granted this is a bit of a workaround and a bit stuffy, but. Hey,  it's another option.

let me know how you go

Comment: Running with an XP mode fixed my issue. No idea what the problem is with Windows 8 though. Im guessing Samsung haven't debugged kies properly.

Comment: Glad to see that it worked, so.. it's obviously a Driver issue, it will work with XP Drivers Under XP Mode but it won't work Under Windows 8, Yes it's also obviously Related to Kies and What Samsung have failed to do thus far, resulting in the Volume Not Mounting

Answer (score 0):

Go to dial pad & type *#0808#

It displays USB settings

Select MTP+ADB option

Press OK button

Connect to USB cable to PC

It shows Connected as a media device."